# Very strange "fact" regarding movement

Tags: mathematical-physics, paradoxes

Perplexing (for me at least) statement from the site: http://www.quora.com/Mathematics/What-are-some-of-the-most-counterintuitive-mathematical-results

> "Fact: You can have a car stand still for hours and then start moving at noon, but its speed, acceleration, meta-acceleration (the rate of change of acceleration), meta-meta-acceleration and so forth were all 0 at noon. How did it then start moving? Miracle."

How is this possible? Is it suggesting/joking with "Miracle", that the velocity function is non-continuous at noon (step function maybe?), or is there some strange solution to

$$ds/dt = 0$$

which isn't a constant $s = c$

Note (I don't know if this image belongs specifically to the above "fact", but it's put right below it on the website):

http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-630e434b5a338247e62b576f73034e24?convert_to_webp=true

Comment: I followed the link, and I'm not sure whether that poster presented his "fact" very clearly or not. There is certainly a lot left unsaid about the dynamics at play. In any case, it is not really a mathematical question about the car's motion, but rather a physics question.

Comment: @rschwieb In my very unqualified opinion: I think that since in the linked website, commentators contest for up-votes, said poster may have sensationalized his "fact" a bit. Really, the whole thread is about counterintuitive "mathematical results", and to make his "fact" more interesting to the average person (like me!), I think he, a bit brutishly, applied it to the real world, where it really doesn't belong.

Comment: I agree with your appraisal :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The position as a function of time can be something like

$$ s(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & t\le 0 \\
  e^{-1/t} & t > 0 \end{cases} $$

This is $\mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R)$, and all derivatives at $t=0$ are $0$.

To prove this, note that every higher derivative in the $t>0$ region has the form $e^{-1/t}P(1/t)$ for some polynomial $P$. Once that is dealt with, it is not too difficult to see that every higher deriviative exists (and is $0$) at $t=0$ too.

Comment: Ahh, so we define t to be 0. Pretty amazing :)! I guess this whole thing is not meant to be physically interpreted, but mathematically, does this imply that even though the derivative at 0, is perfectly 0, in its neighborhood, the integral is not 0, but an infinitesimal? How can that be? Is there an intuitive explanation (or am I off)?

Comment: @Just_a_fool: The derivatives are not $0$ _in a neighborhood_ but only at $0$ itself (and to its left). Anywhere at $t>0$ the value and (most of) the derivatives are nonzero.

Comment: Understanding how to prove this is a bit of a chore.

Comment: This solution makes me curious about what a physicist would say. I had been under the impression that most stuff done in physics was done with analytic functions (and this is an example of a nonanalytic function) but I could be wrong. I wonder if a nonanalytic smooth function would really be something that can be used in a dynamics problem. Maybe that's the whole paradox: one accustomed to thinking in terms of analytic functions might find this example startling.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to say: "Ahh, so we define s(t) to be 0 at 0" ^^

Comment: @rschwieb: I dunno, the "stiffness" of analytic functions strikes me as rather unphysical. I've seen lots of bump functions used in physical modeling, for example -- and they are necessarily not analytic ...

Comment: @rschwieb I suppose that parting from the concept that all physical observations are local (performed during a finite time and bounded region), it is too much to assume that this or that solution should be in fact analytical, but those functions have such nice properties nice properties for usage in a lot of specific cases (e.g. determining the solution of equations of motion of some mechanical system) that they are used as a fine approximation on those bounded regions.

Comment: @YulOtani I see: that sounds about like what I imagined. Thanks :)